# Unity camera auto rotates and causes problems

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I have a camera and I want the camera to follow a player. The player can walk around a cube so the camera must keep it radius to the player.

I'm doing something like the player's z is the x rotation of the camera (with an equation), the problem is, the x rotation of camera goes from 0 to 90, then at 90 it goes again to 0 but changes y and z rotation to 180. That gives me problems because it should keep increasing x rotation up to 180 but it goes from 90 to 0 again because y axis is rotated automatically. How can I dissable this automatication?

```
cameraScene.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(( 180 * (transform.position.z - boxMin.z) / width), 0, 0);
        newPos = new Vector3(0, Mathf.Sin(cameraScene.transform.eulerAngles.x * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * 35 + 25,
            Mathf.Sin((cameraScene.transform.eulerAngles.x-90)* Mathf.Deg2Rad) * 35);
        cameraScene.transform.position = newPos;
```

Comment: please dont post "I'm doing something like ..." post the code in question :D

Comment: @yes updated with code

Comment: what is `boxMin`? what is `width`? is this script attached to the player transform?